# How can Apache serve assets (css, images, scripts) from a different document root?

Tags: apache, webserver

Is there a way to do this? I'd like for my assets to be served from a different document root, and I'm not sure if Apache has directives for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve whole directories from a different location, there's [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html):

```
Alias /assets /path/to/assetsdir
```

works in `httpd.conf` only, though, if you want to point outside the web root.

For specific *files* there is [`AliasMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch).

Comment: I'm looking for something more like how nginx allows. So that if the filetype matches a certain group, then the document root is a different one.

Comment: @Matthew there's `FilesMatch`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch but I don't think it will allows specifying a different document root altogether. I think `AliasMatch` with a regular expression that catches the file types you specify is going to be your best bet.